# MS Word to Powerpoint and back

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, markdown, microsoft-powerpoint-2013, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

We have to create documents in MS-Word, the contents of which are converted to PowerPoint on a regular basis. There are typically dozens of of slides in the PPTX files, and sometimes the number is close to 100. A separate design team constantly updates the colour schems and fonts in the PPTX master templates (could be headers, sidebars, text-boxes, banners, background etc.) The PPTX files are presented in review sessions, content updated regularly. Very often the original MS-Word file content have to be updated as well, for usage later.

Is there a way to define the (XML or other field tags) schema so that the MS-Word and Powerpoint documents are interoperable, and updating one can update the other (not necessarily automatically, but if automated, that's an added bonus).

Are there any Asciidoc or Markdown templates out there for handling these use cases? If there are MS-Office templates - that would be a bonus - because most collaborators and designers are only comfortable with MS Office files.